# Solve the following differential equation: $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a^2y=\cos ax.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Solve the following differential equation: $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a^2y=\cos ax.$

The solution given is as follows:

> The complementary function is $c_1\cos ax + c_2\sin ax$; the particular integral is $\frac{1}{D^2+a^2}(\cos ax)=\frac{1}{-a^2+a^2}\cos ax$; and thus the method fails. In this case, change $a$ to $a+h;$ this gives for the value of the particular integral, $\frac{1}{ D^2 + a^2}\ cos(a + h)x$; this expression, on the application of the
> principle above and the expansion of the operand by Taylor's series, becomes $$\frac{1}{ -(a+h)^2 + a^2}(\cos ax - \sin ax. hx - \cos ax\frac{h^2x^2}{1.2}+...).$$ The first term is already contained in the complementary function, and hence need not be regarded here; the particular integral will accordingly be written  $$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2a+h}(x\sin ax + \frac{hx^2}{1.2}\cos {ax} +\space \text{terms with higher powers of h}\space)\end{align}$$ on making $h$ approach zero, this reduces to $$\frac{x\sin ax}{2a}.$$ The complete integral is $y= c_1\cos ax + c_2\sin ax + \frac{x\sin ax}{2a}.$

Can anyone please help me, understand the Taylor Series expansion for $\cos(a+h)x$ ? They are expanding $f(x)$ about which point ? (I think there's a lack of clarity in here). Neither do I understand, the rest part after that expansion. I am not quite getting it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align}f(x) &=\cos(a+h) x\\&=\cos ax\cos hx-\sin ax\sin hx\\ &=\cos ax\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n (h x)^{2n}}{{2n!}}-\sin ax\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n (h x)^{2n+1}}{{(2n+1)!}}\\&=(\cos ax - \sin ax. hx - \cos ax\frac{h^2x^2}{2!}+\ldots)
\end{align}$

Comment: But from where did you get $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n (h x)^{2n}}{{2n!}}$ ? Is that some expansion for $\cos{hx}$ ?

Comment: Yes. I have used Taylor expansion of $\cos hx$ and $\sin hx$ about $0$.

Comment: But if say, $f(x)=sinhx$ and , then lisiting the first two terms we have, $0, \frac{f'(0)(x-0)^1}{1!}=\frac{(h\cos (h(0)))(x)}{1!}=hx$ ? But this expansion is not matching with yours? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: $\cos ax(1-\frac{x^2h^2}{2! }+\frac{h^4x^4}{4! }+\ldots) -\sin ax(hx-\frac{h^3x^3}{3! }+\ldots) $

Answer (score 0):

You can also leave it as $\cos((a+h)x)$. Then balance it with a complementary solution and apply trigonometric theorems or the mean value theorem
$$
\frac{\cos((a+h)x)-\cos(ax)}{h(2a+h)}=\frac{-\sin((a+h_1)x)}{2(a+h_1)}\xrightarrow{0<h_1<h\to 0}-\frac{x\sin(ax)}{2a}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative solution...

Instead of the guess method,  we can find a particular solution in the following way:

$$y_p=(D^2+a^2)^{-1}(\cos ax)=\frac1{2ai}(D-ai)^{-1}(\cos ax)-\frac1{2ai}(D+ai)^{-1}(\cos ax)\\
=\frac1{2ai}(\frac x2e^{aix}-\frac 1{4ai}e^{-aix})-\frac1{2ai}(\frac x2e^{-aix}+\frac 1{4ai}e^{aix})=\frac{1}{2a}x\sin ax+...$$

So the (general) solution of the  differential equation $(D^2+a^2)y=\cos ax$ is
$$y=c_1\cos ax+c_2\sin ax+\frac{1}{2a}x\sin ax.$$

Comment: Any suggestions on how to guess particular integral jyst like that? Is it just heuristics ?

Comment: I am not diff. expert. But $\frac{1}{D^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{2ai}(\frac{1}{D-ai}-\frac{1}{D+ai})$.

Comment: Ok, but then one has to evaluate $\frac{1}{D-ai}\cos ax -\frac{1}{D+ai}\cos ax$ and say, we consider $\frac{1}{D-ai}\cos ax=p(\text{say})$ in here. This implies $Dp-pai=\cos ax$- now, this is indeed a first order linear differential equation, but, the coefficient of the assummed function $p$ has a complex coefficient i.e $ai$. I haven't learnt complex analysis or complex variable calculus. I have only studied elementary single variable calculus and a bit real analysis. So, I don't know what to do from here ?

Comment: You wanna see $x$? Look: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27-by%3De%5E%28bx%29